# Get the full path of #APP_IMAGES in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want to know the full path of #APP_IMAGES in Oracle Apex which I have uploaded in Shared Component.
I have created one procedure to send email to users in outlook, through that procedure emails are triggering in a scheduled manner.
Please see below code:
`v_mailbody:='<html> <head> </head> <body>'||'Hello '||cur.name||'<br>'||'<br>'||
'<h1 align="center" style="background-color:Tomato;">Happy Birthday! </h1>'||
'<img src="cid: #APP_IMAGES#ncr_img/File_000.jpeg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="500" height="600">'||`

Regards
Anshul Ayushya

Comment: Note: `cid:` is for images embedded in a multi-part mime message. If you want the mail recipients to pull the image from your APEX server you need to provide a static link using the normal `http://` or `https://` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

The `#APP_IMAGES#` form for substitution strings can't be used in PL/SQL. You can call `V('APP_IMAGES')` to get the correct value. That returns a `VARCHAR2`, so you'd use it like:

```
... '<img src="cid:' || V( 'APP_IMAGES' ) || 'ncr_img/File_000.jpeg" ...
```

I'm not sure the `cid` syntax is what you want to use, though.

Comment: even after using `'<img src="' || V( 'APP_IMAGES' ) || '/ncr_img/File_000.jpeg"`
I am unable to see picture in the email... could you please help me with this...

Comment: Is the resulting URL in the src attribute correct for your file? There are multiple reasons it may not be visible in the email.

Answer (score 0):

You can pick the image patch from Shared Components/Static Application Files, which is referred in the Reference Column